# matplotlib 2d numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib

I have created a 2d `numpy` array as:

```
for line in finp:
    tdos = []
    for _ in range(250):
        sdata = finp.readline()
        tdos.append(sdata.split())
    break

tdos = np.array(tdos)
```

Which results in:

```
[['-3.463' '0.0000E+00' '0.0000E+00' '0.0000E+00' '0.0000E+00']
 ['-3.406' '0.0000E+00' '0.0000E+00' '0.0000E+00' '0.0000E+00']
 ['-3.349' '-0.2076E-29' '-0.3384E-30' '-0.1181E-30' '-0.1926E-31']
 ..., 
 ['10.594' '0.2089E+02' '0.3886E+02' '0.9742E+03' '0.9664E+03']
 ['10.651' '0.1943E+02' '0.3915E+02' '0.9753E+03' '0.9687E+03']
 ['10.708' '0.2133E+02' '0.3670E+02' '0.9765E+03' '0.9708E+03']]
```

Now, I need to plot `$0:$1` and `$0:-$2`  using `matplotlib`, so that the in x axis, I will have:

```
tdata[i][0] (i.e. -3.463, -3.406,-3.349, ..., 10.708)
```

,and in the yaxis, I will have:

```
tdata[i][1] (i.e. 0.0000E+00,0.0000E+00,-0.2076E-29,...,0.2133E+02)
```

How I can define xaxis and yaxis from the `numpy` array?

Comment: Perhaps `tdos[0:1,0:-2]`

Comment: thanks...but did not get. Can you kindly explain?

Comment: I interpreted your question as: I want to plot all values from index 0 to index 1 in X, and from index 0 to index -2 in Y. That would be a possible answer. I don't know the significance of `$`in this context.

Comment: Is your question about plotting or indexing (or both)?

Comment: its about plotting...please allow me update the question

Comment: `imshow(tdos[ x0:x1+1, y0:y1+1]` where x0,x1,y0,y0 are the boundaries of the cropped 2d array you want to plot. This way you don't change the original array at all.

Comment: unusual, but then you'd do `p.plot(tdata[:][0], tdata[:][1])`

Comment: another option would be to `np.transpose`, then just plot [1] vs [0]

Comment: `imshow` will plot an image. So you need pixel by pixel information (2D array at least). Can you give a link with an example of plot you are trying to make?

Comment: from your example data - you simply need to plot `tdos[:,1]` against `tdos[:,0]` (note the numpy indexing syntax.  E.g. the line would like `plt.plot(tdos[:,0],tdos[:,1])`.  However - you have other issues if when you print `tdos` it gives you what is shown in "this results in".  That's a `list` of single element `list`s, which themselves contain several strings rather than numbers, so the plot won't work.  Can you confirm the output of `print(tdos)`, after you have converted it to a numpy array?

Answer (score 1):

Just try the following recipe and see if it is what you want (two image plot methods followed by the same methods but with cropped image):

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

X, Y = np.meshgrid(range(100), range(100))
Z = X**2+Y**2

plt.imshow(Z,origin='lower',interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()

plt.pcolormesh(X,Y,Z)
plt.show()

plt.imshow(Z[20:40,30:70],origin='lower',interpolation='nearest')
plt.show()

plt.pcolormesh(X[20:40,30:70],Y[20:40,30:70],Z[20:40,30:70])
plt.show()
```

, results in:

[image: imshow]

[image: pcolormesh]

[image: cropped imshow]

[image: cropped pcolormesh]